# Closure of $A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : x^2 - 4 < y \le7\}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm trying to calculate the closure of:

$$
A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : x^2 - 4 < y \le7\}
$$

I've cheated a bit and plotted the set to get an idea of ​​what the closure might be, so by intuition it can be seen that:

$$
\overline A = B = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2} : x^2-4\le y \le 7 \}
$$

To calculate it, the reasoning that I'm following is to find the set $A'$of its accumulation points, since

$$
\overline A = A' \cup A
$$

Therefore:

$$
(x,y) \in B \Rightarrow  \begin{cases}
x^2-4\le y \lt 7 \phantom{40}\boldsymbol{(1)}\\
x^2-4\le y = 7 \phantom{40}\boldsymbol{(2)}
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\boldsymbol{(1)} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
x \ge 0 \Rightarrow \exists \epsilon_0 > 0: (x-\epsilon_0 ,y)\in B((x,y),\epsilon), (x-\epsilon_0,y) \in A \phantom{1}since \phantom{1} (x-\epsilon_0)^2-4<y \\
x \lt 0 \Rightarrow \exists \epsilon_1 >0:(x+\epsilon_1,y)\in B((x,y),\epsilon), (x+\epsilon_1,y) \in A \phantom{1}since \phantom{1} (x+\epsilon_1)^2-4<y
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\boldsymbol{(2)} \Rightarrow \exists \epsilon_2 \gt 0:(x, y - \epsilon_2) \in B((x,y), \epsilon), (x, y - \epsilon_2) \in A \phantom{1}since \phantom{1} x^2-4 \lt y - \epsilon_2
$$

From this it is concluded that:

$$
\forall \epsilon > 0: B((x,y),\epsilon)\setminus \{(x,y)\} \phantom{1}\cap A \ne \emptyset \Rightarrow (x,y)\in A'
$$

Which means that $B \subset A'$

However I'm not entirely sure if this is enough or if I should prove that there are no more accumulation points of $A$ and thus obtain that $A' \subset B$. And if so, how could you do it? I've been thinking about it and I haven't come up with an easy-to-get contradiction. Any hints or suggestions would be so much appreciated.

Comment: I think the nicer way to do this problem by doing the graph and then that would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the set as the intersection of sets that are more manageable. $A = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 - 4 < y \leq 7\} = \{(x, y) : x^2 - 4 < y\} \cap \{(x, y) : y \leq 7\}$ is the intersection of two sets which we'll call $B, C$ respectively. $C$ is clearly closed. $B$ can be broken into the union of sets $B = \cup_{a \in \mathbb{R}} \{(a, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : a^2 - 4 < y\}$.